# Замена элементов в листе по их индексу начиная с 1 а не 0

Tags: python, list, список, range

Есть лист

```py
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Значения должны быть заменены таким образом

```
list_1 = ['element_1', 'element_2', 'element_3']
```

Начиная с 1 а не 0

Я пробовала так сделать

```
list_1 = ['element_{}'.format(i) for i in range(i+1, len(list_1))]
```

или так

```
list_1 = ['element_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(list_1))]
```

Но если в листе 1 элемент возвращается пустой лист

```
list_2 = ['a']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На выбор:

```
list_1 = ['element_{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(len(list_1))]
```

```
list_1 = ['element_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(list_1)+1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
for i in range(len(list_1)): # Проходим циклом по номерам списка
    list_1[i] = 'element_' + str(i + 1) # элементу списка с текущим номером присваиваем номер + 1, в виде строки
```

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется для данной задачи более уместно использовать [enumerate(iterable, start=1)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> res = [f"element_{i}" for i,x in enumerate(list_1, 1)]

>>> print(res)
['element_1', 'element_2', 'element_3']
```

PS именно для этих целей и была создана функция `enumerate()` ;-)